# Exclude folder from .gitignore rule

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a project where I want to exclude all the pesky *.png files but still want to include the when they are in a specific folder. Essentially, I want to not apply the *.png rule in this folder.
My first attempt did not work.

```
*.png
!results/*
```

Precisely, how to disable certain rules in certain folders?

Comment: I think your question is really similar to this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder

Comment: but it doesnt answer how to disable certain rules in certain folders which is really what i want to ask

Comment: I just tried and it worked for me. I have git version 2.13.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this

```
*.png
!results/*.png
```